# unable to disassemble $PC with gdb core of a java process

Tags: java, gdb

I am looking at the core of a java process that is hung and not responding to any commands. I did a thread stack dump of all threads and what I see is the following pattern repeated....

```
#0  0x00007fc38edbc04f in pthread_cond_wait@@GLIBC_2.3.2 () from /lib/x86_64-linux-gnu/libpthread.so.0
#1  0x00007fc38df34f8b in ?? ()
#2  0x00007fc38800fb00 in ?? ()
#3  0x00007fc38800e800 in ?? ()
#4  0x00007fc38e5c864c in ?? ()
#5  0x00007fc38800c3f0 in ?? ()
#6  0x00007fc38f1df5a0 in ?? ()
#7  0x00007fc38deeaf65 in ?? ()
#8  0x00007fc38f1df5c0 in ?? ()
#9  0x00007fc38800c3f0 in ?? ()
#10 0x00007fc38800e800 in ?? ()
#11 0x00007fc38e5c7f68 in ?? ()
#12 0x00007fc38800e800 in ?? ()
#13 0x00007fc38800f5c0 in ?? ()
#14 0x00007fc38f1df5c0 in ?? ()
#15 0x00007fc38deec5fb in ?? ()
#16 0x00007fc38800e800 in ?? ()
#17 0x000000000000000b in ?? ()
#18 0x00007fc38f1df700 in ?? ()
#19 0x00007fc38dfd66b1 in ?? ()
#20 0x00007fc3455c9af8 in ?? ()
#21 0x00007fc38800e800 in ?? ()
#22 0x00007fc3455c9af8 in ?? ()
#23 0x00007fc300000000 in ?? ()
#24 0x00007fc300000019 in ?? ()
#25 0x0000000000000000 in ?? ()
```

I tried to do an `info mem 0x00007fc38df34f8b` but that didnt work. I am also unable to disassembly any of those frame IPs.

I know that in java, with JIT, the code is generated at runtime. but still, I should be able to disassemble it, right? When I load the core in gdb, it does not complain that it is truncated. Also, I set solib-path correctly to point to jre libs for that process.

Also... I dont think the stack is corrupted. For eg, if I disassembly `pthread_cond_wait` I see the following where it is setting up space for local vars....

```
Dump of assembler code for function pthread_cond_wait@@GLIBC_2.3.2:
   0x7fc38edbbf90 <pthread_cond_wait@@GLIBC_2.3.2>:     lea    rsp,[rsp-0x28]
   0x7fc38edbbf95 <pthread_cond_wait@@GLIBC_2.3.2+5>:   cmp    QWORD PTR [rdi+0x20],0xffffffffffffffff
```

Now looking at `[rsp+40]`

```
(gdb) print $rsp+40
$12 = (void *) 0x7fc38f1df538
(gdb) x/4ga 0x7fc38f1df538
0x7fc38f1df538: 0x7fc38df34f8b  0x7fc38800fb00
0x7fc38f1df548: 0x7fc38800e800  0x7fc38e5c864c
```

You can see that `[rsp+40]` = `0x7fc38df34f8b` matches the IP address of the next frame...

```
#0  0x00007fc38edbc04f in pthread_cond_wait@@GLIBC_2.3.2 () from /lib/x86_64-linux-gnu/libpthread.so.0
#1  0x00007fc38df34f8b in ?? ()
```

Also, looking further in the machine, I see a kern.log file that has the following:

```
2019-07-23T02:13:10.766604+00:00 orc-del-pre-039 kernel: [18512637.857805] java: Corrupted page table at address 61517f050
2019-07-23T02:13:10.766618+00:00 orc-del-pre-039 kernel: [18512637.859136] PGD 800000037c453067 PUD 20df90067 PMD 343ed4067 PTE 80000002a1e4e867
2019-07-23T02:13:10.766618+00:00 orc-del-pre-039 kernel: [18512637.860977] Bad pagetable: 000f [#1] SMP 
2019-07-23T02:13:10.766619+00:00 orc-del-pre-039 kernel: [18512637.861999] Modules linked in: dm_mod tcp_diag inet_diag crc32_pclmul ppdev aesni_intel evdev aes_x86_64 serio_raw lrw gf128mul parport_pc glue_helper ablk_helper pvpanic ena(O) parport cryptd processor button thermal_sys ext4 crc16 mbcache jbd2 crct10dif_pclmul crct10dif_common crc32c_intel nvme
2019-07-23T02:13:10.766620+00:00 orc-del-pre-039 kernel: [18512637.868712] CPU: 5 PID: 11213 Comm: java Tainted: G           O  3.16.0-7-amd64 #1 Debian 3.16.59-1
```

so I am suspecting that something corrupted the PTE and that is why these addresses are not resolvable?

any help appreciated. I am trying to figure out why the process is hung.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

> I should be able to disassemble it, right?

If you are using `disas 0x00007fc38df34f8b`, then no: GDB doesn't know where to start and end the disassembly.

You *can* look at the instructions though: use something like:

```
x/40i 0x00007fc38df34f8b-35
```

This isn't likely to be very helpful though.

There has been a [set of patches](http://sourceware-org.1504.n7.nabble.com/RFC-PATCH-Allow-JIT-unwinder-provide-symbol-information-td255828.html) to make mixed-language debugging work with Java, but I am not sure these patches ever made it.

**Update:**

```
x/40i 0x00007fc38df34f8b-40
0x7fc38df34f63: Cannot access memory at address 0x7fc38df34f63
```

This means that `pthread_cond_wait` doesn't have correct unwind descriptor, and the rest of the output from `where` is bogus.

Comment: thanks for your response. Yeah, I did try `x` but that doesnt work either

Comment: ```(gdb) x/40i 0x00007fc38df34f8b-40
   0x7fc38df34f63: Cannot access memory at address 0x7fc38df34f63
```

Comment: thank you. what is the meaning of `unwind descriptor` ?

Comment: @feroze It sounds like you have a *kernel* bug (page tables are not accessible in user space) or a bad memory. Either can cause a process or the entire system lockup.